# Auto hide launcher in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: unity, launcher, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Vmware 10 on a Windows 10 host machine. I am fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux environment. Whenever I set the launcher to auto-hide, it never comes to the screen again, even after moving the cursor left of the screen or top left of the screen. It only shows if I tap the windows button(super key for Ubuntu) Is it really a problem of Ubuntu 14.04 or Vmware 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the 'reveal sensitivity' of launch bar. So in your case try setting it to high.

Go to Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior and move the bar next to Reveal Sensitivity towards High.

[image]

Comment: Tried that too but it didn't work. I even installed CompizConfig settings manager to set the launcher reveal pressure to 1(which is 20 by default), but still the same problem.